# Trick for converting equations to and from natural units

Tags: special-relativity, notation, units, si-units

Suppose I have an equation, lets say as an example $$E_2=\frac{\sqrt{m^2+M^2+E_1\frac{Mm}{m+M}}}{2}$$
where $m$ and $M$ are masses, $E$'s are energies and this equation is in natural units. Is there a good way to convert back such an equation (but I'm not interested in this particular example) into SI units without doing dimensional analysis on every term? If there is no hope for general natural units, what about if we just take $c=1$, does that make it any easier?. Ideally I'm looking for a trick where I can just look at an equation and say "Oh the c's go there, there, and there".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use dimensional analysis.

All the terms should have the same dimensions, so for example in your formula the left $E$ has dimensions of energy (the same as $mc^2$), so all terms on the right should have energy dimensions (after being square-rooted).

So in order, the terms under the square root should have $c^4$, $c^4$ and $c^2$ after them.